# How can I tell whom a text message is addressed to?

Tags: messages, iphone

I have my iPhone 5S set up so I may receive text messages sent to my email account, my phone number AND my son's phone number. The problem is, when I get a message (say, one that was sent to my son's number) I can't tell if it was sent to ME or HIM.

How can I see this info?

Answer (score 2):

I'd guess you probably can't.

The entire Apple/iCloud paradigm is to be able to get messages to **you** across multiple devices simultaneously.
To make it easy for **you** to deal with those messages wherever you may be.

The last thought of the manufacturers/programmers was to differentiate message recipients inside one device containing multiple **you**s.

Comment: That's a bummer